# Input label hover issue with absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover, pseudo-class

I have `<input type="text"/>` and styles on `:hover`, for example:

```
input:hover {
    border-color: red;
}
```

I want to add search icon to my input. Input `:hover` styles apply well when I hover on the icon, try it:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/kfgggd1b/2/)

```css
input, span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 30px;
}

input:hover {
    border-color: red;
}

span {
    background: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698627-icon-111-search-128.png) 50% 50%/100% 100% no-repeat;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<label>
    <input type="text"/>
    <span></span>
</label>
```

But if I put the search icon visually on the input, the input `:hover` styles don't apply when I hover the icon:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/kfgggd1b/3/)

```css
label {
    position: relative;
}

input, span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 30px;
}

input:hover {
    border-color: red;
}

span {
    background: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698627-icon-111-search-128.png) 50% 50%/100% 100% no-repeat;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<label>
    <input type="text"/>
    <span></span>
</label>
```

**Question:** can I fix this behavior? I want to apply input `:hover` styles when I hover the input at any point.

**P.S.** I know I could set `:hover` styles on `<label>` or set it with Javascript/jQuery, but I don't want to do it because I have many cases of using `<input>` and in other cases I have no `<label>` and an icon, only `<input>`. I'd want the solution without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to add poiter-events rule:

```
span {
    background: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698627-icon-111-search-128.png) 50% 50%/100% 100% no-repeat;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    right: 4px;
    pointer-events: none; <!-- this line -->
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kfgggd1b/4/

But it's not very well supported: http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer

Another approach is to reorganize HTML a little by putting span before input and then

```
span:hover + input, 
input:hover {
    border-color: red;
}
span {
    background: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698627-icon-111-search-128.png) 50% 50%/100% 100% no-repeat;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    right: 4px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kfgggd1b/5/

Comment: `pointer-events: none` is really good point. I prefer this solution for my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can add transparent background to input and place icon absolutely below it (with less z-index).

```
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    label {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        background: white;
    }
    input {
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        height: 30px;
        outline: none;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        background: transparent;
    }
    input:hover {
        border-color: red;
    }
    span {
        background: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698627-icon-111-search-128.png) 50% 50%/100% 100% no-repeat;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        margin-top: -13px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 4px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kfgggd1b/6/)

Comment: Good solution for cross-browser support.